# python3 imaplib search function encoding

Tags: python-3.6, imaplib

Can someone point me out how to properly search using imaplib in python.  The email server is Microsoft Exchange - seems to have problems but I would want a solution from the python/imaplib side.
https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap/issues/128

I so far use:

```
import imaplib
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host_name, port_name)
M.login(u, p)
M.select()
s_str = 'hello'
M.search(s_str)
```

And I get the following error:

```
>>> M.search(s_str)
('NO', [b'[BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)] The specified charset is not supported.'])
```

Comment: You may also want to give IMAPClient a go. It takes care of much of the search encoding aspects for you if you pass search criteria as a unicode string.

Project: https://github.com/mjs/imapclient ;
Relevant docs: http://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#imapclient.IMAPClient.search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`search` takes two or more parameters, an encoding, and the search specifications.  You can pass None as the encoding, to not specify one.  `hello` is not a valid charset.

You also need to specify what you are searching: IMAP has a complex search language detailed in [RFC3501§6.4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4); and imaplib does not provide a high level interface for it.

So, with both of those in mind, you need to do something like:

```
search(None, 'BODY', '"HELLO"')
```

or

```
search(None, 'FROM', '"HELLO"')
```